# SQL for generating financial transaction summary report

Tags: sql, oracle, transactions

[image: Transaction Table]

I have a transaction table like above picture. Now I want to generate a summary report as follows:

[image: Result Table]

What will be the best approach to write the SQL?

Please help. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a requirements description.

Comment: I can do this using common table expression. But I want to know whether there is any better approach. Thanks for the down vote :)

Comment: It's a **summary** (not a *summery*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to get the same result, but without extra grouping:

```
WITH base AS
(
  SELECT Debtor_Acc As Account_NO, Amount*-1 as Amount FROM transaction
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Creditor_Acc, Amount FROM transaction
)
SELECT Account_NO, SUM(Amount) Amount
FROM base
GROUP BY Account_NO
```

Check [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b16df/8)

---

and one more option - without using CTE:

```
SELECT Account_NO, SUM(Amount) Amount
FROM
(
  SELECT Debtor_Acc As Account_NO, Amount*-1 as Amount FROM transaction
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Creditor_Acc, Amount FROM transaction
)
GROUP BY Account_NO
```

Check [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b16df/11)

Answer (score 1):

There are many approaches for achieveing the report. I have used Common table expression.
You can modify the query and use joins aswell.

```
WITH CTE (Account_NO,Amount)
AS
(
SELECT Debtor_Acc As Account_NO,-SUM(Amount) Amount 
FROM transaction GROUP BY Debtor_Acc
UNION
SELECT Creditor_Acc,SUM(Amount) 
FROM transaction GROUP BY Creditor_Acc
)
SELECT Account_NO,SUM(Amount) FROM CTE 
GROUP BY Account_NO
```